# Como puedo hacer una resta de 2 texbox

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer una resta de 2 texbox y mostrarlos en un tercero en tiempo real llamandolo en el textChange del texbox del primero? Por favor si me pueden ayudar es que me marca este error

> **"La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto"**

Como lo intento hacer es asi:

```
public void Cargar(){
    int total, imp, apli; apli = Convert.ToInt32(txtAplicacion.Text);
    imp = Convert.ToInt32(txtImpoSuma.Text); 
    total = imp - apli; txtDif.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Podría ser que estés metiendo numeros decimales?

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int valor1, valor2, res; res = 0;
        valor1 = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        valor2 = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
        res = valor1 - valor2;
        TextBox3.Text = res.ToString();
    }

   // Funciona si TextBox1.Text y TextBox2.Text contienen valores enteros
```

Comment: Agrega una breve descripcion de lo que hiciste para que el usuario pueda entender tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el evento **`TextChanged`** del primer campo así:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  int num1;
  if(!Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out num1))
  {
    Label1.Text = "Numero no valido";
    return;
  }
  int num2;

  if(!Int32.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out num2))
  {
    Label1.Text = "Numero no valido";
    return;
  }
  sum = num1 - num2;
  TextBox3.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```